# Removing the "checked" circle from a RadioButton

Tags: java, android

I want to remove the inner circle from the checked radio button in Android Studio.I've read that `android:button="@null"` would solve it but it removed my whole button. This is my code:

**`RadioButton`**

```
<RadioButton
  android:id="@+id/xroma11"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/radio_bg1"
  android:tag = "00" />
```

**`radio_bg1.xml`**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#333333" />
        <solid android:color="@color/xrwma2"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#333333" />
        <solid android:color="@color/xrwma2"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval"  >
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/xrwma2"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I am sorry

Comment: I have a stroke around the  circle to indicate the selected one

Answer (score 0):

In checked state make color of solid as transparent like this

```
.....

    <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#333333" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
    </item>

.....
```

Comment: This removed the color, not the inner circle

Comment: Do you want to change color of existing radio button?

Comment: No I just want to remove this inner circle that shows which button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `android:button="?android:selectableItemBackground"`